# Accessing and logging the amount of S3 POST/GETs by filename

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have several JSON files in an S3 bucket. I need to do a monthly count of the amount of put/gets each file receives in a month.

Can these be extracted via CSV or even accessed via an API? I have looked at Cloudwatch and there doesn't appear to be an option for this, or within the billing dashboard.

If this feature doesn't exist, are there any workarounds such as a Lamba function with a counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable bucket logs under -

> s3 > bucket > properties > server access logging > configure target
>   bucket/prefix

2. Use Athena to query this data using simple SQL statements. Read more about Athena [HERE](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up access logging for S3 buckets.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

Then you get the ability to export these logs. After that you can do anything with the logs. E.g. a bash script that can count how many requests each file gets.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasksConsole.html